# Laurent Series $e^{\frac1{1-z}}$, $|z|>1$.

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I tried to find Laurent expansion for:

$e^{\frac1{1-z}}$, $|z|>1$.

I tried next: $\frac1{1-z}=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac1{z^n}$,

then using $e^{\frac1{1-z}}=1+\frac1{1-z}+\frac{1}{{2!(1-z)}^2}+\frac{1}{{3!(1-z)}^3}+...$

Then I have   $e^{\frac1{1-z}}$ = $1$ + $(-\frac1{z}-\frac1{z^2}-\frac1{z^3}-...) + (\frac1{2!})(\frac1{z^2}+\frac1{z^4}+…)+...$ = $1 - \frac1z-\frac1{2z^2}-...$.

The result is wrong, since in the book the answer is: $1 - \frac1z+ \frac1{2z^2}-\frac1{6z^3}+\frac1{24z^4}-\frac{19}{120z^5}...$

What I did wrong?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich ... Yes, using invalid steps can make any problems easier.

Comment: @GEdgar Omg I can't believe I said that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $z=\dfrac{1}{w}$ we have $|w|<1$ then by $e^z$ expansion
\begin{align}
e^{\frac{1}{1-z}}
&= e^{\frac{-w}{1-w}} \\
&= \sum_{n\geq0}\dfrac{1}{n!}\left(\frac{-w}{1-w}\right)^n \\
&= \sum_{n\geq0}\dfrac{(-w)^n}{n!}\left(1-w\right)^{-n} \\
&= \sum_{n\geq0}\dfrac{(-w)^n}{n!}\left(1+nw+\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}w^2+\cdots\right) \\
&= \sum_{n\geq0}\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!}\left(w^n+nw^{n+1}+\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}w^{n+2}+\cdots\right)
\end{align}
after calculation some terms we let $w=\dfrac1z$.

---

**Edit:** One may find 
\begin{align}
&1 \\
&-(w+w^2+w^3+w^4+w^5+\cdots) \\
&+\frac12(w^2+2w^3+3w^4+4w^5+\cdots) \\
&-\frac16(w^3+3w^4+6w^5+\cdots) \\
&+\cdots\\
&=1-w-\frac{w^2}{2}-\frac{w^3}{6}+\frac{w^4}{24}+\frac{19 w^5}{120}+\cdots\\
&=\color{blue}{1-\dfrac1z-\frac{1}{2z^2}-\frac{1}{6z^3}+\frac{1}{24z^4}+\frac{19}{120z^5}+\cdots}
\end{align}

Comment: the answer in the book: $1 - \frac1z+ \frac1{2z^2}-\frac1{6z^3}+\frac1{24z^4}-\frac{19}{120z^5}…$. I can't get it.

Comment: See the series and let $n=0$

Comment: so the first is $1$ right?

Comment: yes, the first is 1. I'll try other numbers

Comment: now for $n=1$ it is $-(w+w^2)$

Comment: exactly, i use only $\frac1{z}$, but also can't get $1 - \frac1z+ \frac1{2z^2}$

Comment: and for $n=2,3$

Comment: I found $1-(w+w^2)+\frac12(w^2+2w^3+w^4)-\frac16(w^3+3w^4+3w^5+w^6)+\cdots$

Comment: exactly, then we have  $1-w-\frac1{2}*w^2+...$, but in the book it should be $+\frac1{2}$

Comment: Sorry. my answer has a typo. I'll correct it. Do the calculations again!

Comment: $1-w-\frac1{2}*w^2+...$ instead of +$\frac1{2}$.

Comment: it fixed. . . .

Comment: the coefficient of $\frac1{z^2}$ negative but in the book is positive

Comment: I found $$1-\frac1z-\frac{1}{2z^2}-\frac{1}{6z^3}+\cdots$$

Comment: perhaps it is wrong. I'll check with wolfram now!

Comment: $$1-w-\frac{w^2}{2}-\frac{w^3}{6}+\frac{w^4}{24}+\frac{19 w^5}{120}+\frac{151 w^6}{720}+\frac{1091 w^7}{5040}+\frac{7841 w^8}{40320}+\frac{56519 w^9}{362880}+$$

Comment: that means typo problem in the book?

Comment: $|z|>1$, not oppsite

Comment: Yes. a typo. no matter $$\frac1w=z$$

Comment: type in wolfram alpha 'Laurent Expansion [e^(-w/(1 - w)), {w, 0, 10}] '

Comment: could you please provide a link how to use Wolfram, I'll be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: ok, thank you again

Comment: you are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

Note that$$\left(-\frac1z-\frac1{z^2}-\frac1{z^3}-\frac1{z^4}-\cdots\right)^2=\frac1{z^2}+\frac2{z^3}+\frac3{z^4}+\cdots,$$that$$\left(-\frac1z-\frac1{z^2}-\frac1{z^3}-\frac1{z^4}-\cdots\right)^3=-\frac1{z^3}-\frac3{z^4}-\frac6{z^5}-\cdots,$$and so on. This explains why you got the wrong result.

Comment: sorry, but I can't get the answer from the book. I have again $1 - \frac1z-\frac1{2z^2}-...$, but not $1 - \frac1z+\frac1{2z^2}-...$

Comment: What's the smallest $n$ for which your coefficient of $\frac1{z^n}$ is different from the one from the book?

Comment: the answer: $1 - \frac1z+ \frac1{2z^2}-\frac1{6z^3}+\frac1{24z^4}-\frac{19}{120z^5}…$ As you can see it starts from $\frac1{2z^2}$, $n=2$

Comment: @Metso You forgot the $\frac1{2!}$ that you wrote yourself in the original question.

Comment: result is $1-\frac1z -\frac1{2!z^2}$

Comment: @Metso No, you don't. The only $\frac1z$ in the Laurent expansion is the one coming from $\left(-\frac1z-\frac1{z^2}-\frac1{z^3}-\cdots\right)^1$. So, the coefficient of $\frac1z $ in the Laurent expansion is $-1$.

Comment: can you get $ 1-\frac1z+ \frac1{2z^2}-\frac1{6z^3}+...$?

Comment: No. I see now that there's a problem. The coefficient of $\frac1{z^2}$ is $-\frac12$, not $\frac12$.

Comment: I have several editions of this book and the answer is the same. It's very old book. Strange.

Comment: @Metso Which book is that?

Comment: I. I. Privalov, “Introduction to the Theory of Functions of Complex Variables,” Nauka, Moscow, 1984.

Comment: @Metso There's nothing I can do. I stand by my answer.